# If I install node.js on my server do I need to install Ubuntu or other server OS?

Tags: node.js

**Question** If I install `node.js` on my server do I need to install `Ubuntu` or another server OS?

**Background:** I'm creating a Droplet on `Digital Ocean`.  I am going to use the droplet to host a website that will have a `Discourse` powered forum.  When I create the droplet I have several options, Ubuntu, FreeBSD, Fedora, Debian, CoreOS and CentOS.  I also have the option to install none of these.  Should I install one of these OS?  Or alternately does `node.js` do a good enough job by itself?  Being new to `node.js` do I need something like `NPM`?

**Bonus Point:** Although I know HTML/CSS/Javascript I've always used GoDaddy in the past and I've never had to set up a server before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js is not an operating system. You need something, be it Linux (Fedora, Ubuntu, etc)  or Windows or BSD, but you probably just want to start with Ubuntu.

See this post for a good list of resources on getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Node.JS needs Linux or FreeBSD. You can run it on other operating systems, but this is what Digital Ocean supports.

In Digital Ocean, you can choose CentOS, then after it is running, you can type:

```
yum install npm
```

This will install `node`, `npm` and some other related programs.